# How do I redirect traffic to my blog using Namecheap?

Tags: amazon-web-services, wordpress, hosting, url-routing

My website is hosted on github and my www and @ points to github. My website is working fine. I recently made a Wordpress blog that is hosted on AWS. I want to direct blog.mydomain.com to AWS EC2. Is that possible to do without using Masked URL Redirect? Does that hurt SEO? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To point a subdomain at AWS you just change DNS, nothing complicated is required. It makes no difference to DNS that it's different from the main domain.

Yes it will hurt SEO a little to have your blog on a different domain than the main - a subdomain is a different domain to Google.

Given you have an EC2 server you have a couple of things you could do

- Host the static website on EC2 instead of github (probably best), and link to github for downloads
- Install Nginx, proxy the static website through to Github, and host the blog from a subdirectory. Proxying to github means you may get a small duplicate content penalty from Google.

Comment: hi tim thanks for replying, does that mean adding a new A record that point to the public elastic ip for the ec2 instance of where the blog is?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Your subdomain A record points to the EC2 elastic IP address.

Comment: i did that and it working but the url changes, is there a way to do this without the url changing. this is the link: test.gogenieapp.com, thanks

Comment: i tried using cname to the link but it's still the same. test2.gogenieapp.com

Comment: This comes down to configuration of your application, it's not related to DNS. Suggest if you need help with that you need to create another questions, as it's technically unrelated to your original question.